# Nginx unknown directive "upstream" error when deploying Rails

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I am trying to install an standard Rails app. After going through a tutorial https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha I am stuck at last step.

When trying to restart nginx I get the following error -
`Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "upstream" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1 ;  nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

I have strictly followed all the steps in https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha so my conf files and unicorn.rb files are pretty much same with changes in projectname and user.

My nginx conf file - http://pastebin.com/bd0RRDxK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `nginx.conf` mentioned here https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha is supposed to be put in your rails app at `config/nginx.conf`.

This file is then sym linked for nginx to be picked up.

Comment: so what should  I do about the file I changed /etc/nginx/nginx.conf ?
Revert it? Or leave it as is?

Comment: Let it be what it was before and follow the pro-tip instructions.