# Deploying Rails app using Nginx, Unicorn, Postgres and Capistrano to Digital Ocean : nginx eror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn, digital-ocean

I have done all the steps by using this [tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha) but while running  below statement, I am getting the following error. I have created my Digital Ocean VPS host in port 3000.

```
$ sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
$ sudo service nginx restart
* Restarting nginx nginx   [fail] 
$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] "listen" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/hosting:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nginx unknown directive "upstream"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349057/nginx-unknown-directive-upstream)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the solution here:
[Nginx unknown directive "upstream" error when deploying Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349057/nginx-unknown-directive-upstream)

That guy followed the same tutorial, and had the exact same problem. He also posted a solution.

Also, to avoid the issue altogether, you might consider using this plugin: https://github.com/bruno-/capistrano-unicorn-nginx